# add blue tiles to matplotlib plot (background)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So when I want to plot this

```
plt.plot(np.cumsum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_))
plt.xlabel('number of components')
plt.ylabel('cumulative explained variance');
```

The result looks like:
[image]

But the above plot is not beautiful. What I want it to look like is similar to:
[image]

I did some search before asking here to no avail. Would appreciate if I given a hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick, dirty fix is `import seaborn as sns; sns.set()` before your plot command. And then call `seaborn.reset_orig()` when you want the original `pyplot` style.

Comment: @NavidRashedi because it doesn't really solve your problem with `matplotlib` but depends on another package. Glad it works for you though :-).